# Sharing Isolated Power supply for CAN and RS485

Tags: can, isolation, rs485

I am using [ISO1432](https://www.ti.com/product/ISO1432) from TI for isolated RS485 transceiver function. And [ISO1042](https://www.ti.com/product/ISO1042) for Isolated CAN transceiver. Both devices requires an isolated supply on bus side. Can I use one isolated 5V DC-DC converter and use the supply out for both the transceivers?
Is there any issue will be there if I use the same supply for both the interfaces?

Comment: Will they be used simultaneously?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Yes. It will be used simultaneously.